# Imagem de cabeçalho não aparece com print();

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com um problema e por mais que pareça simples não estou conseguindo entender e por consequência, resolve-lo, minha chamada a página foi alterada ficando agora dessa forma, o mesmo está assim:

```
$(function() {

 $('#frmCadastro').validate({
    rules: {
        Nome: {
            required: true
        },
        Cpf: {
            required: true
        },
        Data: {
            required: true
        },
    },
    // Messages for form validation
    messages: {
        Nome: {
            required: ''
        },
        Cpf: {
            required: ''
        },
        Data: {
            required: ''
        }
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var data = $(form).serialize();
        //event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "pImpreComDispTemporaria.php",
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'text',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {

                console.log(data);

                var janela = window.open("", "", "width=800,height=1000");
                janela.document.write(data);
                janela.focus();
                janela.print();

            }
        });
        return false;

    }
    });

    });
```

Mas a imagem que está no topo nunca é exibida, a página está assim:

```html
<body>

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
 <tr>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr valign="center">
  <td height="82" colspan="2" align="left">     
  <img src="../_imagens/logo-employer.gif" width="244" alt=""/>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
 </tr>   
</table>
```

A imagem está no diretório correto e a chamada está certa, se cancelar, fechando a janela de impressão o cabeçalho com a imagem é exibido corretamente.

Comment: retirei a resposa por não ter ajudado neste caso

Comment: É essa a imagem que não aparece? `../_imagens/logo-employer.gif` ou é alguma outra? Normalmente quando a imagem é usada no `background` ela não aparece na hora da impressão...

Comment: Olá @hugocsl, é essa imagem mesmo que não aparece.

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui chamando a img por uma URL e funcionou normal, apareceu direitinho... `src="http://placeskull.com/160/160"`

Comment: mas  a  imagem não está aparecendo ou  está ficando um quadradinho  tipo  nessa  imagem ? https://superuser.com/questions/712082/images-not-loading-in-most-browsers

Comment: Olá @MarcosBrinnerpikatoons, a imagem não aparece mesmo, não fica com esse quadradinho

Comment: estranho, tente definir no style="display:inline !important"
não consegue colocar a imagem  para carregar em  um caminho  absoluto?
tipo site.com/imagem/local/item.gif ?

Comment: Ela está em caminho absoluto @MarcosBrinnerpikatoons, estranho de mais